# How to return a string from a C++ function?

Tags: c++, string, return-value

This is a simple sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string replaceSubstring(string, string, string);

int main()
{
    string str1, str2, str3;

    cout << "These are the strings: " << endl;
    cout << "str1: \"the dog jumped over the fence\"" << endl;
    cout << "str2: \"the\"" << endl;
    cout << "str3: \"that\"" << endl << endl;
    cout << "This program will search str1 for str2 and replace it with str3\n\n";

    cout << "The new str1: " << replaceSubstring(str1, str2, str3);

    cout << endl << endl;
}

string replaceSubstring(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
    int index = s1.find(s2, 0);

    s1.replace(index, s2.length(), s3);

    return s1;
}
```

It compiles however the function returns nothing. If I change `return s1` to `return "asdf"` it will return `asdf`. How can I return a string with this function?

Comment: You don't actually initialise your string variables.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem in returning the string? Check the values of the strings inside the function.

Comment: The text you output is just text to the compiler - it won't try to figure out what that text means, and won't keep your promises for you. After all, maybe you *meant* to lie to the user.

Comment: So I guess you get down votes for make a dumb mistake? Oh, well.

Comment: @fredsbend - downvotes mostly mean it's not an interesting question. It's not much fun for newbies who want to earn some reputation, but most newbie questions aren't interesting even to most other newbies - they'll make their own mistakes, and they won't be able to find your question if they make the same mistake anyway. The usual term is "too localized". You got help - don't worry too much about the high score table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You never give any value to your strings in `main` so they are empty, and thus obviously the function returns an empty string.

Replace:

```
string str1, str2, str3;
```

with:

```
string str1 = "the dog jumped over the fence";
string str2 = "the";
string str3 = "that";
```

---

Also, you have several problems in your `replaceSubstring` function:

```
int index = s1.find(s2, 0);
s1.replace(index, s2.length(), s3);
```

- `std::string::find` returns a `std::string::size_type` (aka. `size_t`) not an `int`. Two differences: `size_t` is unsigned, and it's not necessarily the same size as an `int` depending on your platform (eg. on 64 bits Linux or Windows `size_t` is unsigned 64 bits while `int` is signed 32 bits).
- What happens if `s2` is not part of `s1`? I'll leave it up to you to find how to fix that. Hint: `std::string::npos` ;)

Comment: Yeah. It's late. Bone head move. Thanks.

Comment: @fredsbend: I just added another issue (unrelated to your question) with your code. See my edit.

Comment: I have since addressed point two with a while loop that breaks if `index` is greater than `s1.length()`. The effect is that it now replaces all instances of `s2` with `s3`. I am unfamiliar with `size_t` though I have come across it.

Comment: @fredsbend: an `if` is enough, no need to use a `while`. As for `size_t`, it is important that you get used to it. :) To avoid that in the future, my best advice would be to systematically verify the documentation for every API you use until you are comfortable with it. [cppreference](http://cppreference.com/) is a good place for that. I know it's tedious but that's the best way to learn *and* write good code at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

```
string str1, str2, str3;

cout << "These are the strings: " << endl;
cout << "str1: \"the dog jumped over the fence\"" << endl;
cout << "str2: \"the\"" << endl;
cout << "str3: \"that\"" << endl << endl;
```

From this, I see that you have not initialized str1, str2, or str3 to contain the values that you are printing. I might suggest doing so first:

```
string str1 = "the dog jumped over the fence", 
       str2 = "the",
       str3 = "that";

cout << "These are the strings: " << endl;
cout << "str1: \"" << str1 << "\"" << endl;
cout << "str2: \"" << str2 << "\"" << endl;
cout << "str3: \"" << str3 << "\"" << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign something to your strings. This will definitely help.